# Trying to make a program that checks if a password contains uppercase letter and a number in c

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am trying to make a program that checks whether the password created contains an uppercase letter and a number. Both the for loops execute fine if only one of them is written without the other (one loop works fine if I comment out the other loop), but if I type them both together only the second for loop (that's associated with checking if there is a number or not) works and the other doesn't work.

So with the written code below, if I type a password that does not contain an uppercase letter nor a number I get the "Please make sure that your password contains a number and try again." message only.

Note :

- I tried using the assigning the integer i to zero after the first loop and using it in the second loop instead of x but I get the same result.
- I am using code::blocks compiler.

Could anyone point out where did I go wrong?

Sorry if the question isn't clear enough this is my first question here in stackoverflow, and thanks in advance.

The code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()

{

    char password[25];

    int i;

    int x;

    printf("Create a strong password (must contain an uppercase letter and a number, and must be at least 8 characters) :\n");
    scanf(" %s", password);



    for (i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
    {

        if ( isupper(password[i]) == 1 )
        {
            break;
        }

        if (i == 25)
        {
            printf("\nPlease make sure that your password contains an uppercase letter and try again.\n");
        }


    }


      for (x = 0; x <= 25; x++)
    {

        if (isdigit(password[x]) == 1)
        {
            break;
        }

        if ( x == 25 )
        {
             printf("\nPlease make sure that your password contains a number and try again.\n");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One major problem is that the loop `for (i = 0; i <= 25; i++)` *will* go out of bounds. It will also disregard the end of the string (if it's less than 24 characters).

Comment: `isupper` does not return specifically `1`, but a *non-zero* value to be `true`. So `if(isupper(password[i]) == 1)` should be `if(isupper(password[i]))`

Comment: `if (isupper((unsigned char)password[i])) /* ... */;` to allow for password to have, for example, the `'π'` character

Comment: You should also stop reading after encountering the `\0` (null) character.

Comment: isupper() returns Non-zero integer ( x > 0 ) when argument is an uppercase alphabet, returns 0 when argument is not an uppercase alphabet.
Alternate way is to compare with the ASCII values. if(password[i] >= 65 && password[i] <= 90).

Comment: It's a shame you're not using c++ because you can do this a lot more elegantly using regular expressions...

Comment: @auburg Hm, I fail to find an elegant regular expression that matches passwords with the given criteria. Btw. you can use regular expressions in C as good as in C++

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What do you mean by a "for loop going out of bounds"?  Sorry I am still learning C and I don't know what does that mean.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Yes, after checking out the answer below I found out that the code works fine only if I made it stop reading when encountering the null zero. I optimized the program after reading my mistakes mentioned in the comments, but the only thing that made a difference is the null zero. Do you have any idea why the program won't work if I didn't make it stop reading after encountering the null zero (even after fixing my mistakes)?

Comment: Because the null character tells you where the string ends. If the input password is less than 25 characters, you will read beyond the end of the input, which contain garbage values.

Comment: @GoodDeeds That's a reasonable answer. Thanks for the help mate!

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= 25; i++)` will *include* the index `25`, which is element number 26 in the array (of 25 elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues in your code, which I shall attempt to address here.

First, as mentioned in the comments, your two `for` loops will (most likely) go "out of bounds" as array indexes in `C` start at **zero** and end at "n - 1" (where "n" is the size of the array).

Second, the `isupper()` and `isdigit()` functions do not (necessarily) return "1" for a 'positive result' - the [specification](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isupper/) states only that they return **non-zero**. So, we can just test the return value as a 'Boolean' value (zero will equate to 'false' and **any** non-zero will equate to 'true').

Lastly, rather than run your `for` loops for the entire `password` buffer, you need only run until the terminating `nul` character is found - at which point you will know that a required uppercase letter or digit  is not including in the string.

Here's a 'working' version of your code, with comments added where I've made changes:

```c
int main()
{
    char password[25];
    int i;
    int x;
    printf("Create a strong password (must contain an uppercase letter and a number, and must be at least 8 characters) :\n");
    scanf(" %s", password);
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) { // password[24] is the last possible element - NOT password[25].
        if (isupper(password[i])) { // "isupper()" will return NON-ZERO (but not necessarily 1!)
            break;
        }
        else if (password[i] == '\0') { // we've reached the end of the string and not found an uppercase...
            printf("\nPlease make sure that your password contains an uppercase letter and try again.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    for (x = 0; x < 25; x++) { // as before, use "x < 25" rather than "x <= 25"
        if (isdigit(password[x])) { // "isdigit()" will return NON-ZERO (but not necessarily 1!)
            break;
        }
        else if (password[x] == '\0') { // we've reached the end of the string and not found a digit...
            printf("\nPlease make sure that your password contains a number and try again.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And maybe `scanf(" %24s", password);`

Comment: `for (i = 0; password[i]; i++)` is probably the better condition anyway (you just have to make sure, that the conversion in `scanf()` succeeded previously. This would however require some more changes...

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a simple function:

```
int isCapitalAndDigit(const char *pwd, int minsize)
{
    int isCapitalLetter = 0, isDigit = 0;
    size_t len = 0;

    while(*pwd && (!(isDigit && isCapitalLetter) || len < minsize) )
    {
        if(isdigit(*pwd)) isDigit = 1;
          else if(isalpha(*pwd) && !islower(*pwd)) isCapitalLetter = 1;
        pwd++;
        len++;
    }
    return isDigit && isCapitalLetter && (len >= minsize);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/53XrhW

Comment: Your code will treat any of these: `+=&*£$` (and many more) as 'Capital Letters'!

Comment: Yes, but now you have `isalpha(*pwd) && !islower(*pwd)` which is a very bizarre way of re-encoding `isupper(*pwd)` - is it not?

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am a still learning C and I didn't learn about creating my own functions yet. And that's my bad I forgot to mention it while typing the question. I will make sure to check out your answer once I learn about creating functions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's c++ code that uses regular expressions (with a bit of work this should be do-able in C ?)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "tkfgfff3gf";


    std::regex word_regex("(\[[:upper:]])");    


    auto words_begin = 
        std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), word_regex);
    auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    int count =std::distance(words_begin, words_end);

    if(count == 0)
    {
        std::cout<<"Please make sure that your password contains an uppercase letter and try again";
    }

    std::regex number_regex("(\[0-9])");

    auto number_begin = 
        std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), number_regex);
    auto number_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    count =std::distance(number_begin, number_end);

    if(count == 0)
    {
        std::cout<<"Please make sure that your password contains a number and try again";
    }

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am still learning C and didn't learn anything about C++ yet. And that's my bad I forgot to mention in it in the question.

Comment: Yes i wasn't expecting you to be able to use this, this is more to show you how much easier using reg expressions are.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyways mate. Much appreciated!!